# Breaking equations within the align environment

Tags: align, amsmath

I currently have these two equations, but they are too long to fit on one line:

```
\begin{align*}
            [((a_0, a_1, a_2)+(b_0, b_1, b_2)) + (c_0, c_1, c_2)] &= 
            [((a_0 + b_0, a_1 + b_1, a_2 + b_2)) + (c_0, c_1, c_2)] \\
            &= (a_0 + b_0 + c_0, a_1 + b_1 + c_1, a_2 + b_2 + c_2) \\ 
\end{align*}
```

I want to achieve something to this effect:
[image: desired look]

I have tried using the split environment within the align environment, but that doesn't allow me to align the line breaks, while also keeping the equal signs independently aligned. I am also open to alternative ideas on how to make this look better. (I do not think the second equality looks great in my mockup.)

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Why do you want to break these equations? Each fits on a single line.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). IMO, I think you should just begin the `=` on a subsequent line.

Comment: @Bernard The stuff after the equals sign goes into the margin. (I am doing this within an enumerate environment so that might cause it to go into the margin for me.)

Comment: @PeterGrill Like this? http://i.imgur.com/RBc3Yzf.png

Comment: It goes slightly into the margin, that is true, but doesn't if you load `geometry`, which defines more sensible margins than the default – unless you use marginal notes. If you don't, with the defaults of geometry, it's fits within text width.

Comment: @Lsonic: Yep, I'd just add a `\quad` before the `=` on each line.

Comment: If the problem is that it goes into the margin your example should demonstrate that, preferably a complete small document that sets the page size that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two more alternatives:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}

    \begin{document}
    The first option:
\begin{align*}
[((a_0, a_1, a_2) + & (b_0, b_1, b_2)) + (c_0, c_1, c_2)]         \\
    & = [((a_0 + b_0, a_1 + b_1, a_2 + b_2)) + (c_0, c_1, c_2)] \\
    & = (  a_0 + b_0 + c_0, a_1 + b_1 + c_1, a_2 + b_2 + c_2)  
\end{align*}
The second one:
\begin{align*}
[((a_0, a_1, a_2) + (b_0, b_1, b_2)) + (c_0, c_1, c_2)]     
    & = \begin{multlined}[t]
            [((a_0 + b_0, a_1 + b_1, a_2 + b_2))\\
                 + (c_0, c_1, c_2)] 
        \end{multlined}\\
    & = \begin{multlined}[t]
            (  a_0 + b_0 + c_0, a_1 + b_1 + c_1, \\
                    a_2 + b_2 + c_2)
        \end{multlined}
\end{align*}
    \end{document}
```

They gives:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

yet another possibility -- use `aligned` within `multline`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{multline*}
 [((a_0, a_1, a_2)+(b_0, b_1, b_2)) + (c_0, c_1, c_2)] \\
 \begin{aligned}
   &= [((a_0 + b_0, a_1 + b_1, a_2 + b_2)) + (c_0, c_1, c_2)] \\
   &= (a_0 + b_0 + c_0, a_1 + b_1 + c_1, a_2 + b_2 + c_2)
 \end{aligned} \\
\end{multline*}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

Answer (score 1):

Try using `eqnarray` like this:

```
\begin{eqnarray}
            [((a_0, a_1, a_2)+(b_0, b_1, b_2)) + (c_0, c_1, c_2)] & = &
            [((a_0 + b_0, a_1 + b_1, a_2 + b_2))  \\
            &   &              + (c_0, c_1, c_2)] \\
            & = & (a_0 + b_0 + c_0, a_1 + b_1 + c_1, \\
            &   & a_2 + b_2 + c_2) \\ 
\end{eqnarray}
```

you might need `\nonumber` to suppress equation numbering, since this it still pretty wide.

Comment: For reference, see [`eqnarray` vs `align`](http://goo.gl/3R7Ln)...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest putting the `=` on its own line along with a `\quad` spacing before the `=`.  To ensure that the first line does not effect the alignment use `mathrlap`.

Also, if you are using this within an `enumerate` list, then you can use `aligned`.  This is assuming that there is not additional text before the math environment.  Otherwise, use `align*`.

[image]

### Notes:

- There should *not* be a `\\` in the last line of a display math environment.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*} 
    \mathrlap{[((a_0, a_1, a_2)+(b_0, b_1, b_2)) + (c_0, c_1, c_2)]} \\
        &\quad= [((a_0 + b_0, a_1 + b_1, a_2 + b_2)) + (c_0, c_1, c_2)] \\
        &\quad= (a_0 + b_0 + c_0, a_1 + b_1 + c_1, a_2 + b_2 + c_2) %\\  <--- No \\ on last line.
\end{align*}
Within an enumerate
\begin{enumerate}
\item
$\begin{aligned}[t]
    \mathrlap{[((a_0, a_1, a_2)+(b_0, b_1, b_2)) + (c_0, c_1, c_2)]} \\
        &\quad= [((a_0 + b_0, a_1 + b_1, a_2 + b_2)) + (c_0, c_1, c_2)] \\
        &\quad= (a_0 + b_0 + c_0, a_1 + b_1 + c_1, a_2 + b_2 + c_2) %\\  <--- No \\ on last line.
\end{aligned}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution by manually inserting white space:

```
\begin{align*}
            [((a_0, a_1, a_2)+(b_0, b_1, b_2)) + (c_0, c_1, c_2)] &= 
            [((a_0 + b_0, a_1 + b_1, a_2 + b_2)) \\
            &~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + (c_0, c_1, c_2)] \\
            &= (a_0 + b_0 + c_0, a_1 + b_1 + c_1,\\
            &~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ a_2 + b_2 + c_2) \\ 
\end{align*}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Wouldn't `\hspace{<length>}` be more convenient?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hack: introduce a new variable, like so:

```
We now compute the sum $S$ of our three vectors:
\begin{align*}
S&=[((a_0, a_1, a_2)+(b_0, b_1, b_2)) + (c_0, c_1, c_2)]\\
 &=[((a_0 + b_0, a_1 + b_1, a_2 + b_2)) + (c_0, c_1, c_2)]\\
 &=(a_0 + b_0 + c_0, a_1 + b_1 + c_1, a_2 + b_2 + c_2) 
\end{align*}
```

This costs an extra line, but is well worth it in my opinion.